# Computing the log-likelihood term

Tags: bayes-theorem, empirical-bayes

I´m currently reading the paper "The Little Engine that Could
Regularization by Denoising (RED)" by Yaniv Romano and Micheal Elad. In the beginning they come up with solving the Maximum aposteriori Probability (MAP) for an given (measured) image $y$ and a unknown image $x$. So one tries to solve ${argmax}_x P(x\vert y)$ which is equivalent to solving ${argmin}_x -log(P(y\vert x)) -log(P(x))$. The term $l(y,x)=-log(P(y\vert x))$ is also know as the log-likelihood term. Then there is written that $l(y,x)=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\vert\vert Hx-y\vert{\vert}_2^2$ if $y=Hx+e$, where $e$ is a gaussian noise with variance $\sigma^2$, and $H$ is a linear Operator. This is what I don´t get. Can anybody help me to compute the log-likeliehood term $l(y,x)$ for the case that $y=Hx+e$?

Thanking you in anticipation,

Christian

Comment: The book has to make some assumption about the distribution $P(y|x)$, like for instance assuming it's a gaussian or something like that.

Comment: We only know that $e$ has a gaussian distribution. Do we really need further assumption? The result is also dependent on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem statement initially. The book is correct. I'll show you why in a few moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prior assumption is that $y=Hx + e$, where $e$ follows a gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and covariance $\sigma^2I$. Let me restate this using the notation $p(e) = \mathcal{N}(e|0, \sigma^2I)$.

This assumption implies that $p(y|x)=\mathcal{N}(y|Hx, \sigma^2)$ (note that we are considering a conditional distribution where $x$ is given, so we may see $x$ as deterministic).

Therefore, assuming the vectors $x$ and $y$ are $k$-dimensional,

\begin{align}
-\log p(y|x) &= -\log \left(\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{(2\pi)^k}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(y-Hx)'\sigma^{-2}I(y-Hx) \right) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}||y-Hx||^2 + \text{const.}
\end{align}

Assuming $\sigma^2$ is fixed, the "const." is a constant and, therefore, does not affect the arg min.